# I want to implement a dropdown which is sublist to an item

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a list I'm using for side-menu but I want to implement a sublist to dropdown when a list item is tapped or clicked but I don't know how to go about it.

Example:

**Your Account**
 - Wishlist
 - Orders
 - Recommendations
**Categories**
 - Gear
 - Nursery

Where when "Your Account" is tapped the list below it shows and same for Categories being the first-level list in the menu.

Thanks in advance.